# Less pejorative tag for "commie plot" questions?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, tags

One of the more paranoid cold war devices in the American rhetorical armamentarium is the accusation of a given reform being a *"Communist Plot"*.  This device has been so overused and successfully parodied, that even though Communists sometimes really have plotted, such accusations now seem almost quaint and tend to imply more about the accuser than the accused.

All of which is brought to mind by Fizz's Q:

[What's the highest level of official recognition that an African country gave to their “brothers” in the US?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/32881/whats-the-highest-level-of-official-recognition-that-an-african-country-gave-to)

...which seems like a perfectly good question, but which also, (I had incorrectly suspected), seemed as though it were indirectly serving to [Red Bait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-baiting) another user here who's asked a somewhat related question. (*Fizz* has later pointed out this resemblance is an accidental coincidence.)

For similar questions, I'd suggest a *"Commie Plot"* tag, but phrased perhaps in some way less obnoxious to conservatives.  A few stabs at it:

- Communist Plot (lost its meaning...)
- Cold War Plots (more general, might be either side, or different opposing nations and doctrines)
- Marxist Tactics (still a bit heated)
- Ulterior motives (vague, might fairly be applied to all questions)
- Kremlin Compatible (just kidding)

None of those seem satisfactory...

Comment: Can you link to some other question(s) that would actually benefit from it? (I mean besides mine.) That might inform the choice of name for the tag better.

Comment: "Pulling a Putin"?

Answer (score -5):

How about [venona-project](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/venona-project)?

Named after https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venona_project which proved beyond a reasonable doubt that just because you're a paranoid conspiracy theory monger, that doesn't actually mean *they* aren't out to get you.

Comment: Unless all such plots must forever involve at least one of those names cited in the *Venona Project*, that tag name would be too narrow.